# Isotope percentage based column widths and centering with isFitWidth : true

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, fluid-layout

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/X6C9P/4/

Percentage based Isotope items behave strangely with the masonry {isFitWidth: true} option. Click the 'transition' button several times to see the behavior I'm talking about.

Changing the .item to a fixed width gives the desired result.

I've looked at this hack, but it doesn't have any affect on this isFitWidth option. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html

Anyone know of a way to center items with percentage based widths?

Relevant code:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

.item {
    width: 33%;
}

var $container = $('#container').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode: 'masonry',
  masonry: {
    isFitWidth: true  
  }
});
```